# an application of implicit function theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I need to proof the following, could any one help me to proof step by step?
$(t,\epsilon)\mapsto F(t,\epsilon):\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a twice continuously differentiable function, assume that $F(0,0)=0$, $F_t'(0,0)=F_{\epsilon}'(0,0)=0$, then there exist $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for any $\epsilon\in(0,\epsilon_0)$ and any positive $0$ of the polynom $$p(d)=2F_{tt}''(0,0)d^3+2F_{t\epsilon}''(0,0)d^2+(F_{\epsilon\epsilon}''(0,0)-F_{tt}''(0,0))d-F_{t\epsilon}''(0,0)$$ such that $$J:=\frac{1}{2d}F_{t\epsilon}''(0,0)+\frac{1}{2}F_{tt}''(0,0)\neq 0$$ the equation $$F(t,\epsilon)=0$$ has a unique solution $t(\epsilon)$ in the interval $[\epsilon\sqrt{d^2-\epsilon M},\epsilon\sqrt{d^2+\epsilon M}]$
I have not geometrically understood the picture of the statement, I also want to know what are the tools(theorem,results, books) I need to understand clearly the above result.please help,ths is very important for me. thank you.

Comment: You have not defined $M$, I don't think.

Comment: $M>0$ is a fixed number.